# Timeout doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, reload

```
function updateimage(){
 $("#fileimg").attr("src","secondimage.jpg");
 $('#fileimg').fadeIn('slow');
}
setTimeout(updateimage(), 5000);
```

This is the code i tried. Its a code to reload the image every 5 seconds. But it doesn't work. I get this error in IE: Invalid argument
Can y'all help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 options:

```js
setTimeout("updateimage()", 5000)
```

or use a function:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
        updateimage();
}, 5000);
```

Comment: When I hit Answer, there were no answers.  When I submitted my answer there we 4 more. LOL.

Answer (score 10):

You should pass the actual function as argument and not the call:

```
setTimeout(updateimage, 5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

`setTimeout('updateimage()', 5000);`

Answer (score 1):

According to the microsoft documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536753(v=vs.85).aspx) it the parameter has to be either a function pointer or a string. So both the twerks below will work.

**Method 1**

```
setTimeout(updateimage, 5000);
```

**Method 2**

```
setTimeout("updateimage", 5000);
```

Comment: I don't see how this adds anything beyond the existing answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
setTimeout(updateimage(), 5000);
```

Remove the parenthesis from updateimage, so it is:

```
setTimeout(updateimage, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated you are calling it wrong.

What you have there:

```
function updateimage(){
 $("#fileimg").attr("src","secondimage.jpg");
 $('#fileimg').fadeIn('slow');
}

setTimeout(updateimage(), 5000);
```

When executed this will pass the *result* of `updateImage()` to the `setTimeout()` call.  As your function returns no value, you are in effect actually saying:

```
setTimeout(null, 5000);
```

Pass the function by its name, as if it were a variable of that name, which indeed it is.

```
setTimeout(updateimage, 5000);
```

Comment: This should have been accepted, it gives much more information than the other answers.